# How can I install ClockworkMOD Recovery on a Sony Ericsson W8?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, sony-ericsson-w8

Is it possible to install ClockworkMOD Recovery on a Sony Ericsson W8 with Android 2.1? ROM Manager is asking for the phone model, and W8 is not listed nor any Xperia phone.  Is there a different version for my device?

Answer (score 2):

According to directions on [this site](http://answers.downloadatoz.com/q,6408,how-to-install-cyanogenmod-7-1-gingerbread-2-3-4-on-sony-ericsson-w8.html), there is a non-official (and therefore unsupported) version of Clockworkmod Recovery for the W8 available [here](http://mirrorbrain.cyanogenmod.com/cm/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-3.0.2.8-speedy.img).  It doesn't provide instructions on installing it, but I imagine you do it with either fastboot, or ODIN/Heimdal.

Alternatively, use xRecovery as described in [these instructions](http://myw8.blogspot.com/2011/07/installing-and-using-xrecovery.html).  It's very similar to CMR, but according to the site you will need ROMs packaged specifically for this recovery:

> **Note:** Make sure that the zip files are made for Xrecovery. (zip
>   files for cwm are different)